# How to set access control allow origin in socket io

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I am using socket.io and express js. I want to set access control allow origin to the socket connection

I've tried setting the origins property when initializing socket

`var io = require('socket.io')(http, {origins: 'http://www.example.com'})`

[image: In the image below access control allow origin is set to *]
In the image above access control allow origin is set to *. I want to set that to example.com (also note the request method is GET)

[image]
In this image however the access control allow origin header is set (also note the request method is POST)

How can I add the access control allow origin header when the request method is GET. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
io.set('origins', 'http://yourdomain.com:80');
```

Or you can also try `server.origins` like below:

```
io.origins((origin, callback) => {
  if (origin !== 'https://foo.example.com') {
    return callback('origin not allowed', false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
});
```

By returning `true`, you allow the origin. Otherwise, send the error message. Refer docs [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-origins-fn)

Answer (score 0):

please try below in express main file

// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

```
// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://yourdomain.com:80');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

   // Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In Express you can use like this:

`app.all('*(or set for what way you exectly need)', function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.example.com');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'your headers');
    next();
});`

Also in the socket.io you do not need to specify separately headers for POST or GET... this is a different communication protocol. 
Here is example for socket set you can try:

`io.set( 'origins', '*www.example.com' );`

Answer (score -1):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Comment: Hi! While this may be a solution to the question, code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Please take some time to edit your response with an explanation as to why this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors of the site.